# Different color in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

[image]

I have used two color: light color `#607D8B` for app bar and dark color `#455A64` for above appbar. But problem is, navigation drawer display two different color other then I mentioned. I don't know why the different color come to the navigation drawer. So, what can be done to solve this issue ?

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="#455A64"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/ex_list_items"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:childDivider="#00000000"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml code ??

Comment: Yes,posted my xml